# android ScrollView minimizes my items height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I created a CardView (custom view) and uses it in a LinearLayout : 4 rows of 4 CardViews.
i want each row to be the only one displayed on screen - and scroll between them.

When i use only LinearLayout (without ScrollView) - i see that the ViewCards first row is at the size of the screen - like i want.
BUT - when i add the ScrollView it shrinks all 4 rows to the size of half of main screen.
(i tried putting the ScrollView inside/above a new wrapping/inner LinearLayouts - all causes same wrong (for me) results)

THIS IS THE XML WITHOUT ScrollView :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

            <com.example.trytoget.ViewCard
                android:id="@+id/viewCard16"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </com.example.trytoget.ViewCard>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

where and how should i put my ScrollView?

my ViewCard.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"

     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#111111"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardFront"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#111111"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
</FrameLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView.